# Unwanted code in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a strange message in header in Wordpress. It belows on my navigation bar in the wordpress. I do not know how to fix the code. Help people, please..
I have installed plugins but nothing new. The problem has occurred today.

At first I thought I had a syntax error but I tested the code and it is ok.

For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYwFv.png)
Whether the problem is in any other file?

How can i remove this? May be I have an error in header.php...I dont know.
That is my header.php file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="isie ie7 oldie no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="isie ie8 oldie no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="isie ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-W5FZJCF');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
 <?php is_dt_theme_moible_view(); ?>
<script charset="UTF-8" src="//cdn.sendpulse.com/28edd3380a1c17cf65b137fe96516659/js/push/c62b1197420513c7a9c7298ef1e2bb6e_1.js" async></script>


 
 <meta name="author" content="designthemes">
 <title><?php dt_theme_public_title(); ?></title>

 <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
 <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<?php
 global $dt_allowed_html_tags;
 #Load Theme Styles...
 if(dt_theme_option('integration', 'enable-header-code') != '') echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.wp_kses(stripslashes(dt_theme_option('integration', 'header-code')), $dt_allowed_html_tags).'</script>';
 wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-W5FZJCF"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) --> <?php if(dt_theme_option("appearance","layout") == "boxed") body_class('boxed'); else body_class(); ?>
 <?php if(dt_theme_option('general','loading-bar') != "true") echo '<div id="loader-wrapper"><div class="loader"><span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span></div></div>'; ?>
 <!-- **Wrapper** -->
 <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <!-- header-wrapper starts here -->
   <?php $htype = dt_theme_option('appearance','header_type'); $htype = !empty($htype) ? $htype : 'header1'; ?>
         <div id="header-wrapper" class="<?php if(dt_theme_option('general','header-top-bar') == "true") echo esc_attr('notop-bar'); if($htype == 'header3') echo esc_attr(' header3-wrapper'); ?>">
             <header id="header" class="<?php echo esc_attr($htype); ?>">
    <?php if(dt_theme_option('general','header-top-bar') != "true"): ?>
                    <!-- Top bar starts here -->
                    <div class="top-bar">
                        <div class="container">
       <?php if(dt_theme_option('general', 'top-bar-left-content') != NULL && $htype != 'header5'): ?>
                                <div class="dt-sc-contact-info">
                                    <p><?php echo wp_kses(do_shortcode(stripslashes(dt_theme_option('general', 'top-bar-left-content'))), $dt_allowed_html_tags); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php elseif($htype == 'header5'):
                             echo do_shortcode('[dt_social/]');
                            endif; ?>
                            <div class="top-right">
                                <ul><?php
        if(function_exists("is_woocommerce")): ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View Shopping Cart', 'iamd_text_domain' ); ?>"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a></li><?php
        endif;
        if(!is_user_logged_in()):
         $loginurl = ( class_exists('c_ws_plugin__s2member_check_activation') ) ? wp_login_url() : wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>
         <li><a title="<?php _e('Login', 'iamd_text_domain'); ?>" href="<?php echo $loginurl; ?>"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span><?php _e('Member Login', 'iamd_text_domain'); ?></a></li>
         <li><a title="<?php _e('Register Now', 'iamd_text_domain'); ?>" href="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>"><span class="fa fa-user"></span><?php _e('Register', 'iamd_text_domain'); ?></a></li><?php
        else: ?>
         <li><a title="<?php _e('Logout', 'iamd_text_domain'); ?>" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>"><span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span><?php _e('Logout', 'iamd_text_domain'); ?></a></li>
         <li><a title="<?php _e('My Profile', 'iamd_text_domain'); ?>" href="<?php 
          $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
          echo get_edit_user_link($current_user->ID); ?>"><span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span><?php _e('My Profile', 'iamd_text_domain'); ?></a></li><?php
        endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Top bar ends here -->
                <?php endif;
    if($htype == 'header3'): ?>
                    <div id="logo"><?php
                        if( dt_theme_option('general', 'logo') ):
                            $template_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
                            $url = dt_theme_option('general', 'logo-url');
                            $url = !empty( $url ) ? $url : $template_uri."/images/logo.png";

                            $retina_url = dt_theme_option('general','retina-logo-url');
                            $retina_url = !empty($retina_url) ? $retina_url : $template_uri."/images/logo@2x.png";

                            $width = dt_theme_option('general','retina-logo-width');
                            $width = !empty($width) ? $width."px;" : "187px";

                            $height = dt_theme_option('general','retina-logo-height');
                            $height = !empty($height) ? $height."px;" : "49px";?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url());?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>">
                                <img class="normal_logo" src="<?php echo esc_url($url);?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>" />
                                <img class="retina_logo" src="<?php echo esc_url($retina_url);?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>" style="width:<?php echo esc_attr($width);?>; height:<?php echo esc_attr($height);?>;"/>
                            </a><?php
                        else: ?>
                            <div class="logo-title">
                                <h1 id="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></a></h1>
                                <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
                            </div><?php
                        endif; ?>                                 
                    </div>
     <div class="main-menu-container">
                     <div class="main-menu">
                            <div id="primary-menu">
                                <div class="dt-menu-toggle" id="dt-menu-toggle"><?php _e('Menu','iamd_text_domain'); ?><span class="dt-menu-toggle-icon"></span></div>
                                <nav id="main-menu">
                                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container'  => false, 'menu_id' => 'menu-main-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'fallback_cb' => 'dt_theme_default_navigation', 'walker' => new DTFrontEndMenuWalker())); ?>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><?php
    else: ?>
     <div class="main-menu-container">
                     <div class="main-menu">
                            <div id="logo"><?php
                                if( dt_theme_option('general', 'logo') ):
                                    $template_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
                                    $url = dt_theme_option('general', 'logo-url');
                                    $url = !empty( $url ) ? $url : $template_uri."/images/logo.png";
    
                                    $retina_url = dt_theme_option('general','retina-logo-url');
                                    $retina_url = !empty($retina_url) ? $retina_url : $template_uri."/images/logo@2x.png";
    
                                    $width = dt_theme_option('general','retina-logo-width');
                                    $width = !empty($width) ? $width."px;" : "187px";
    
                                    $height = dt_theme_option('general','retina-logo-height');
                                    $height = !empty($height) ? $height."px;" : "49px";?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url());?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>">
                                        <img class="normal_logo" src="<?php echo esc_url($url);?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>" />
                                        <img class="retina_logo" src="<?php echo esc_url($retina_url);?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>" style="width:<?php echo esc_attr($width);?>; height:<?php echo esc_attr($height);?>;"/>
                                    </a><?php
                                else: ?>
                                    <div class="logo-title">
                                        <h1 id="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></a></h1>
                                        <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
                                    </div><?php
                                endif; ?>  
                               
                            </div>
                            <div id="primary-menu">
                                <div class="dt-menu-toggle" id="dt-menu-toggle"><?php _e('Menu','iamd_text_domain'); ?><span class="dt-menu-toggle-icon"></span></div>
                                <nav id="main-menu">
                                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container'  => false, 'menu_id' => 'menu-main-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'fallback_cb' => 'dt_theme_default_navigation', 'walker' => new DTFrontEndMenuWalker())); ?>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><?php
    endif; ?>
    </header>
   </div>

<?php putRevSlider('slider1', 'homepage'); ?>
```

I turned off all the plugins and that appeared again.

If there is something to show it i will.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hard to tell, probably something in the theme, take a look on the source code of the page and look for 'no-customize-support', check to what container it belongs, probably is something you can remove from the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inspecting the message element from the Developer Tool of the web browser to see if there is any broken html code. Here is how to do that in Chrome https://developer.chrome.com/devtools